# What is Hadoop TestDFSIO's unit of measurement?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

When looking at HDFS troughput, TestDFSIO uses "mb/sec" as the unit of measurement. Is this MegaBytes/s, Megabits/s or MibiBytes/s? I suspect it is Megabytes/s, but cannot find clear documentation on this.

example output:

```
15/07/06 09:59:33 INFO fs.TestDFSIO: ----- TestDFSIO ----- : read
15/07/06 09:59:33 INFO fs.TestDFSIO:            Date & time: Mon Jul 06 09:59:33 CEST 2015
15/07/06 09:59:33 INFO fs.TestDFSIO:        Number of files: 10
15/07/06 09:59:33 INFO fs.TestDFSIO: Total MBytes processed: 10000.0
15/07/06 09:59:33 INFO fs.TestDFSIO:      Throughput mb/sec: 17.08896343474494
15/07/06 09:59:33 INFO fs.TestDFSIO: Average IO rate mb/sec: 18.49329376220703
15/07/06 09:59:33 INFO fs.TestDFSIO:  IO rate std deviation: 5.178436159603544
15/07/06 09:59:33 INFO fs.TestDFSIO:     Test exec time sec: 93.996
```

Note that it is not possible to derive the unit by using the total MBytes and the test exec. time, as throughput is measures using the sum of map times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it **Mega Bytes per second**. Source: refer to "about the math" https://support.pivotal.io/hc/en-us/articles/200864057-Running-DFSIO-mapreduce-benchmark-test